# why <input = "file"> on modal can't pass image to php

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog

I'm rookie at php and html, i have this modal that has  in it which i need for inserting an image..

```
if (isset($_POST['add_roomtype_action'])) {
    require 'script/addRoomType.php';
}

<div class="modal fade" id="add_roomtype_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
aria-labelledby="add_roomtype_modal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
hidden="true">&times;</button>
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Room Type</h4>
          </div>
            <form action="room_management.php" method="post" 
autocomplete="off">
          <div class="modal-body">

            <input type="hidden" id="upd_roomtype_id" name = 
"add_roomtype_idnm">
            <label style="font-size: 10pt">Room Type : </label>
            <input type="text" id="add_roomtype" name = "add_roomtypenm" 
 style="font-size: 10pt" ><br></br>
            <label style="font-size: 10pt">Rate : </label>
            <input type="text" id="addupd_rate" name = "add_ratenm" 
style="font-size: 10pt" ><br></br>
            <label style="font-size: 10pt">Image : </label>

            <input type="file" id ="add_roomtypeImgid" 
name="add_roomtypeImgnm" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg">

             </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-
dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn" id = "add_roomtype_action" 
name = "add_roomtype_action">Add</button>
          </div>    
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the php file which the modal will call

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = ""; 
    $dbname = "afgroms";


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['add_roomtype_action'])){
    $roomtypeid = $_POST['add_roomtype_idnm'];
    $roomtype = $_POST['add_roomtypenm'];
    $rate = $_POST['add_ratenm'];
    $file = $_FILES['add_roomtypeImgnm'];
    $fileName = $file['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $file['size'];
    $fileError = $file['error'];
    $fileType = $file['type'];






    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png');

    if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if($fileError === 0)
        {
            if ($fileSize > 500000) {
                mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_roomtype` SET `RoomType` = 
'$roomtype', `Rate` = '$rate', `Image` = '$img' WHERE RoomTypeID = 
".$roomtypeid);
                echo "<script>";
        echo "alert(\"Successfully Added!\");";
        echo "</script>";
            }else{
                echo "<script>";
        echo "alert(\"File size too big!\");";
        echo "</script>";
            }
        }else
        {
        echo "<script>";
        echo "alert(\"There was an error\");";
        echo "</script>";
        }

    }else
    {
        echo "<script>";
        echo "alert(\"You cannot upload this type of file\");";
        echo "</script>";

    }
    }
?>
```

but this error keep on occurring : Notice: Undefined index: add_roomtypeImgnm...
help me out here guys, i don't know whats the problem. I already tried to change the name and id of my  and same error keeps on occurring.

Comment: Try it with multipart form data...

Comment: what is that sir?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: my problem is just piece of code : enctype="multipart/form-data" .. i've been struggling all night!

Comment: Yes. The process of self teaching is painful. Sometimes it is smarter to go to bed. The morning solves most of all problems.

Comment: And i bet that you'll never forget that you can only post files with this enctype for the rest of your life. Remember that things will get easier with each of these lessons. Keep it up!

Comment: hahaha, Thank you so much sir, you are so kind :D

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot post files is not your modal dialog but the fact that you are not using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.

Try it like this and it should work.